# is there any way to convert datetime format in dataframe without changing dtype in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i have a dataframe which has field name Date,i want to convert date format from y/m/d/ to d/m/y, 
 i used

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d ').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

i get d/m/y form but it become **object datatype**,i want to get result in **datetime** dtype

Comment: Hi, object datatype is string datatype of dataframe, if you stop at `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d ')` it will be datetime data type, the step later `strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` is to convert `datetime` to `str`

Comment: how can i get d/m/y in datetime data type?

Comment: Hi, why do you need it as datetime data, the d/m/y you are talking about is not datetime type, it is string

Comment: could you include your actual data so I can answer base on your understanding?

Comment: Hi, writing excel is a different story, i supposed you write to excel by `pd.to_excel`, can you leave it as datetime data type, then write to excel and to see if it is what you need?

Comment: i used pd.to_excel,when i  convert datetime data type,i become y/m/d format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208463/discussion-between-kiran-gopi-and-phung-duy-phong).